# Update to Spring Boot 1.4.1 from 1.3.2 breaks interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I have the following interceptor for OAuth request template

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class OAuthInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private AppContext appContext;

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
        try {
            if (appContext != null) {
                requestTemplate.header("X-Forwarded-For", appContext.getIpAddress());
                ...
```

And the AppContext is an object associated with an user session

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value="session")
public class AppContext implements Serializable {
    ...
```

On 1.3.2 everything is OK, and the interceptor can read the appContext var, on 1.4.1 appContext will throw a BeanCreationException.

I can't figure out the reason.

EDIT: Here it is the stacktrace.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.appContext': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(CglibAopProxy.java:687)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:637)
    at com.xxx.api.AppContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c81ccd31.getIpAddress(<generated>)
    at com.xxx.api.interceptor.OAuthInterceptor.apply(OAuthInterceptor.java:34)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.targetRequest(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:158)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:88)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:108)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:294)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:289)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$5.call(AbstractCommand.java:521)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$5.call(AbstractCommand.java:499)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
    ... 33 more
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.appContext': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(CglibAopProxy.java:687)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:637)
    at com.xxx.AppContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c81ccd31.getIpAddress(<generated>)
    at com.xxx.api.interceptor.OAuthInterceptor.apply(OAuthInterceptor.java:34)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.targetRequest(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:158)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:88)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:108)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:294)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:289)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$5.call(AbstractCommand.java:521)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$5.call(AbstractCommand.java:499)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: It is better to put your full exception log here.

Comment: @LipingHuang, thanks. I've updated with the stacktrace. The issue looks very similar to execute the same via Scheduler, but this used to work on 1.3.2

Comment: Ok, adding "feign.hystrix.enabled=false" works for now.